# Creating a data that follows a spcific data distribution

Tags: python, random, statistics, distribution

I have a variable `x` of 2700 points. It is my original data.

The **HISTOGRAM** of my data looks like this. The cyan color line is the distribution my data follows. I used `curve_fit` to my histogram and obtained the fitted curve. The fitted curve is a numpy array of 100000 points.

[image]

I want to generate a smoothed `random data`, of say 100000 points, that follows the **DISTRIBUTION** of my `original data`. **`i.e in principle I want 100000 points below the fitted curve, starting from 0.0 and increasing in the same way as the curve till 0.5`**

What I have tried so far to get 100000 points below the curve is:

I generated uniform random numbers using `np.random.uniform(0,0.5,100000)`

```
random_x = []

u = np.random.uniform(0,0.5,100000)

for i in u:
    if i<=y_ran:  # here y_ran is the numpy array of the fitted curve
        random_x.append(i)
```

But I get an error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I know the above code is not the proper one, but how should I proceed further?? 
`

Comment: @JanneKarila yes it is. I had to entirely rephrase my question. So I wrote a new one

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem in the following way: first, fit your `y_ran` fitted curve to a gaussian (see for instance [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507028/fit-a-gaussian-function) question), and then draw your sample from a normal distribution with known coefficients by [`np.random.normal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) function. Something along these lines will work (in part taken from the answer to the question I'm referring to):

```
import numpy
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit    

# Define model function to be used to fit to the data above:
def gauss(x, *p):
    A, mu, sigma = p
    return A*numpy.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2.*sigma**2))

# p0 is the initial guess for the fitting coefficients (A, mu and sigma above)
p0 = [1., 0., 1.]

coeff, var_matrix = curve_fit(gauss, x, y_ran, p0=p0)

sample = numpy.random.normal(*coeff, (100000,))
```

Note: 1. this is not tested, 2. you'll need x values for your fitted curve.

Comment: for my fitted curve in the above, I used x = np.linspace(0,0.5,100000)

Comment: Ok, then you have x. Fit your curve to a gaussian and then draw the sample from it.