# SciPy - fit a Gaussian envelope

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, gaussian

I have a numerically calculated light pulse's temporal shape, stored in a NumPy array. I'd like to find the parameters (specifically, the FWHM) of it's Gaussian envelope function, but for that first I have to fit it.
Is there a built-in SciPy function, or set of functions, for envelope fitting, or I have to write this code myself? (As accuracy is not too important, I'd probably just take the local maxes and fit a Gaussian on them...)

The light pulse looks like this:

[image: The light pulse in question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to find the maxima, I suggest using Scipy's [argrelextrema](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html).

It however seems to me that you would want to use Scipy's [Hilbert transform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hilbert.html)
in order to find an analytic form for the envelope. You can then generate an array for the envelope to which you can fit a Gaussian.

For the Gaussian fit there is a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507028/fit-a-gaussian-function).