# Reproducing Excel's LINEST function with NumPy

Tags: python, excel, numpy, linear-regression

I have to use Excel's LINEST function to compute error in my linear regression. I was hoping to reproduce the results using Numpy's polyfit function. I was hoping to reproduce the following LINEST  usage:

`LINEST(y's, x's,,TRUE)`

with polyfit. I'm not sure how I can get the two functions to produce the same values because nothing I've tried gives similar results.

I tried the following:

`numpy.polyfit(x,y,3)`

and various other values in the third position.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [6th degree curve fitting with numpy/scipy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143174/6th-degree-curve-fitting-with-numpy-scipy)

Comment: I've read that SO question. I would like to reproduce the default LINEST function, not a specific degree polynomial. 

I edited the post to include the code that I tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is actually a result of my misunderstanding of NumPy's polyfit function and LINEST. Doing the following:

```
 numpy.polyfit(x,y,1)
```

gave me the correct result because it performs a linear regression using the sample `x` and `y` values like LINEST.

Comment: Makes sense now. LINEST, for n columns, looks like y = m1*x1 + m2*x2 + ... + mn*xn.

Which are all linear in the x's, hence the degree 1 fit.